# Вывод всех категорий внутри карточки товара битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс, битрикс24

В данным момент я реализовал вывод, но получаю только одну категорию(последнюю)

```
<?$res = CIBlockSection::GetByID($arResult["IBLOCK_SECTION_ID"]);
if($ar_res = $res->GetNext())
?>
<a href="<? echo $ar_res['SECTION_PAGE_URL']; ?>">
<span><? echo $ar_res['NAME']; ?></span>
</a>
```

А хотелось бы получить весь список категорий, к которым относится данный товар.

Comment: У вас у товара который в нескольких разделах поле `$arResult["IBLOCK_SECTION_ID"]` содержит все разделы где этот товар есть или там у вас всегда только 1 раздел? Если там несколько, то делайте просто перебор через `foreach` этого поля. А внутри `foreach` исполняйте ваш фрагмент кода.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант Nikolaj Sarry в комментарии к вашем вопросу
или

```
<?$res = CIBlockElement::GetElementGroups($ELEMENT_ID, false, ['NAME', SECTION_PAGE_URL']); 
while($ar_res = $res->Fetch())
{
?>
  <a href="<? echo $ar_res['SECTION_PAGE_URL']; ?>">
  <span><? echo $ar_res['NAME']; ?></span>
<?  
}
?>
```

[Документация по данному методу](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblockelement/getelementgroups.php)

В файле result_modifier.php, для кеширования.